# Escaping values in mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have the following values pulled from a csv file:

```
vars = (
  '001U0000016lf5jIAA', 
  'Bam Margera Presents: Where the #$&% is Santa? (Unrated)', 
  'a0KU000000JMpgzMAD'
)
```

How would I insert these? This is what I'm currently doing but it's giving a SQL error probably because of the unescaped `%` in the second var --

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', vars)
```

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Note: I'd rather keep the vars as-is (without trying to escape anything within it and just modify the SQL/python statement.

Comment: What are your exact errors?

Comment: @HaraldNordgren added in.

Comment: Why `line` is passed to `execute()` and not `vars`?

Comment: @alecxe sorry typo, please see updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you sure the `vars` has this exact value when the error happens?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `%`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query = '''INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', vars
cursor.execute(db.escape_string(query))
```

or

```
escaped = tuple(db.escape_string(x) for x in vars)
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%s, %s, %s)''', escaped)
```

Comment: What is `db` ? is this `MySQLdb`, or what is the import statement for that.

Comment: It's your DB connection object. The one you got the cursor from.